# PHP check if file exists and not directory

Tags: php

I read the `file_exists()` can also return turn if it points to a directory. What is the fastest way to check if only a file exits?

At the moment I have:

```
/**
 * Check if the file exists.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function exists() {
    if(is_null($this->_file)) return false;

    return (!is_dir($this->_file) && file_exists($this->_file)) ? true : false;
}
```

I found lots of posts relating to checking if file exits in PHP but nothing that talks about the directory and how best to check this.

This method can get called 1000s of time so I could really do with making it as fast as possible.

Comment: What result should you get for *symlinks* to files?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're looking for the [`is_file`](http://php.net/is_file) function:

```
public function exists() {
    return $this->_file !== null && is_file($this->_file);
}
```

Comment: From the docs: "Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB." Is this anything to worry about? 99% of the time no file will ever reach this size unless its a log file out of control

Comment: Also this puts me off using is_file http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php#46845

Comment: @John Hard to say. *Some* ***may*** return unexpected results... I have not encountered a case where this was a problem. YMMV.

Comment: @John And that second concern is pretty nonsensical, since that works the same for *all relative paths* in all functions. Which is why you typically want to avoid using relative paths.

Answer (score 4):

```
public function exists() {
    return !is_dir($this->_file) && file_exists($this->_file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for **file only**. Its a custom function you will call  instead of `file_exists` function

```
 function custom_file_exists($filePath)
    {
          if((is_file($filePath))&&(file_exists($filePath))){
            return true;
          }   
          return false;
    }
```